# What's the best module for interacting with HDFS with Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, hdfs, python-hdfs

I see there is hdfs3, snakebite, and some others. Which one is the best supported and comprehensive?

Comment: As of 2019, the last updated version of `snakebite` on pypi is Aug 8 2016.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, there are not as many possibilities as one may think. But I'd suggest the official Python Package `hdfs 2.0.12` which can be downloaded the [website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdfs/) or from terminal by running:

```
pip install hdfs
```

Some of the features:

- Python (2 and 3) bindings for the WebHDFS (and HttpFS) API,
  supporting both secure and insecure clusters.
- Command line interface
  to transfer files and start an interactive client shell, with aliases
  for convenient namenode URL caching.
- Additional functionality through
  optional extensions: avro, to read and write Avro files directly from
  HDFS. dataframe, to load and save Pandas dataframes. kerberos, to
  support Kerberos authenticated clusters.

Answer (score 8):

I have tried snakebite, hdfs3 and hdfs.

Snakebite supports only download (no upload) so it's no go for me.

Out of these 3 only hdfs3 supports HA set up, so it was my choice, however I didn't manage to make it work with [multihomed networks](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsMultihoming.html) using datanode hostnames (problem described here: https://rainerpeter.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/connect-to-hdfs-running-in-ec2-using-public-ip-addresses/)

So I ended up using hdfs (2.0.16) as it supports uploads. I had to add some workaround using bash to support HA.

PS. There's interesting article comparing Python libraries developed for interacting with the Hadoop File System at http://wesmckinney.com/blog/python-hdfs-interfaces/

Answer (score 8):

`pyarrow`, the python implementation of apache arrow has a well maintained and documented HDFS client: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html

Answer (score 1):

There's `pydoop`, which is quite handy.

https://github.com/crs4/pydoop

Answer (score 0):

I found pyhdfs-client really good for large files. (File taking 1 hour with webhdfs got loaded in 18 mins with it).

```
pip install pyhdfs-client
```

Only downside is, it's new and it's interface is not clean as compared to other hdfs clients. Documentation is missing however you can check usage here: https://pypi.org/project/pyhdfs-client/